# Improving the transference speed via sockets JAVA

Tags: java, sockets

first of all, im making a bomberman and i want it to work in LAN. the game has a main loop in which it moves the bomberman, sends and receive information through sockets using TCP. using a server and then it paints all it needs to paint. The problems is that the refresh rate of the game shoud be a refresh every 50ms approximately (20fps) and it takes  127ms(average) to send and receive all the data the game needs to continue with the loop. so, it moves the bomberman, and it waits way to long for the data to be retrieved before re-drawing the screen. in less words, the game runs slow because of the slow transference rate of the packets. the packets are not really big (at least i think so), they contain 5 ints and a image .GIF 60x30.

the problem is not only that the time (in average) it takes to send and receive the packets is too long. its also that its not constant, sometimes it takes just 0ms and other times 1000ms. so there goes my first question:

Why does this happen? why the time it takes to send and receive the package is so variable?

my code for the transference work this way: the game retrieves the package (the info from the other game) and send its own package to the server using an auxiliary thread class that sends and receive from the server the packages and stores them in  an attribute. the thread start running (sending/receiving) while tha game draws what it needs in the screen. and then the game waits for the thread to finish his task to move to the next iteration. I made it this way hoping that while the game was drawing, the other class could work in the transference, thus, giving it a little more time to do its work so the game had to wait less for it to finish. It worked, but the difference wasn't big enough.

--------------------------this is the code for the game loop (only the data sending part)--------------------

```
  while (Running)                    

                packet = DataExchange.retrieve(); //DataExchange is the auxiliary class object

                    //decompress the received package
                    Sprite =packet.Sprite.getImage();
                    X = packet.coordenadaX;
                    Y = packet.coordenadaY;
                    B = packet.M; //M is a class with 3 integers

                     packet.SetPacket(b1.x, b1.y, new PaqueteImagen(b1.SpriteActual) , BombaAliada); //Compress the packet that the game will send

                     DataExchange.SetPacket( packet ); //set the packet of the auxiliary class to the packet that will be sent.

                     Thread t = new Thread( DataExchange );
                     t.start();  //start the trasference thread      


                 if (b1.isAlive()) controlPj.MovePj(); //moves the bomberman (b1)

                  Draw(); //here the game draws in the screen. 



               while (t.isAlive()); //waits for the auxiliary thread to end.
           }
          setVisible(false);
       }
```

-----------------------------this is the auxiliary class------------------------

```
public class DataExchange implements Runnable {
   ObjectOutputStream output =null;
   ObjectInputStream input = null;
   PaqueteBomberman packet;
   Socket socket;


public DataExchange( Socket socket, PacketClass P){ //constructor
    this.socket = socket;
    packet = P;
}

public  PacketClass retrieve ( ){ //get packet
    return packet;
}

public void SetPacket(  PacketClass P){ //set packet
    packet = P;
}

@Override
public void run(){   
                try{

                    output = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                    output.flush();
                    input = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

                    output.writeObject(packet); //sends the packet to the server

                     packet = (PacketClass) input.readObject();//receives the packet from the server

                }
                catch(Exception e){}
}
}
```

------------------------------This is the code of the server-------------------

```
public class Server {

private ServerSocket serverSocket = null;   
private Socket socket = null;
private Socket socket2 = null;
public boolean conected = false;

 private ObjectInputStream Packetinput = null;
 private ObjectOutputStream Packetoutput = null;

 private ObjectInputStream Packetinput2 = null;
 private ObjectOutputStream Packetoutput2 = null;


private PacketClass packet1 = null;
private PacketClass packet2 = null;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
   Server Servidor = new Server();

   Servidor.run();
}

public void run() throws Exception{

        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(208);     

        socket = serverSocket.accept(); //socket for player 1          

        socket2 = serverSocket.accept(); //socket for player 2        

        conected=true;                          

        while ( conected ){
              //=====create ImputStream and    OutputStream================================


              Packetinput = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
              Packetoutput = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

              Packetinput2 = new ObjectInputStream(socket2.getInputStream());
              Packetoutput2 = new ObjectOutputStream(socket2.getOutputStream());



            //==========receives the package from one player and sends it to the other=================

              packet1 = (PacketClass) Packetinput.readObject();
              packet2 = (PacketClass) Packetinput2.readObject();

              Packetoutput.writeObject(packet2);
              Packetoutput2.writeObject(packet1);

        }

        socket.close();

  }
}
```

thats the LAN part of the game. here comes the second question: Any idea of how to really improve the data transference speed so that the game loop doesnt have to wait so long for the data it needs? i need a really good improvement, something like from 120ms to 60-80ms, any thoughts?

Comment: Not really an answer but if I'm not mistaken, the game shouldn't be interacting with the server so much (waiting on a server response for every frame you want to draw is insane). What you should normally do is interact with your server for specific events. For example, when the player is moving the bomberman, you send the server a notification that the character has moved, but the client itself will update without waiting for a response. Also if an enemy player moves, the server is the one that should notify the client about the required update, don't have the client poll the server for it.

Comment: @konstantine that's a great idea, don't know how didn't i think about it. but i think the problem still remains, for example, what happens if i let the key pressed? the server will get many notifications of movement and the transference rate wouldn't let it correspond to all of them. i may be wrong, what do you think?

Comment: I'm not really an expert on networked game programming but I'm sure your problem is very common and should have been addressed all around the internet. One idea would be for your client side to filter all input and send to the server only specific data. Say you keep "Left Arrow" pressed for 1 sec. The client registers 20 presses at 20 fps but the bomberman moves only 1 tile. The client need only send 1 state change of the game not 20.